# how to use titan.email in django to send email to the users

Tags: python, django

I got titan.email account when i bough AWS hosting
How to use this email account to send email to the users in djago

```
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.titan.email'
EMAIL_HOST_USER='admin@test.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='password'
EMAIL_PORT= 465
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_SSL=True
```

I am getting this error while sending email

```
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (504, b'5.5.2 <webmaster@localhost>: Sender address rejected: need fully-qualified address', 'webmaster@localhost')
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked after adding this

```
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.titan.email'
EMAIL_HOST_USER='admin@test.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='password'  
EMAIL_PORT= 465
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_SSL=True

ADMIN_EMAIL = "admin@test.com"
SUPPORT_EMAIL = "admin@test.com"
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = ADMIN_EMAIL
SERVER_EMAIL = ADMIN_EMAIL
```